# Where are the bodhisattvic principles in Hinduism?

Tags: buddhism, samsara

It is said that the Buddha reached the Enlightenment for the welfare of all human beings and to free them from the bondage of Samsara.

Where are the most significant passages of the bodhisattvic principles / vows in our texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddha did not reach enlightenment for the welfare of all human beings and free them from bondage. Buddha was initially reluctant to do anything for others regarding it as a hopeless task. It was Lord Brahma who requested Buddha to teach the dharma to others.

> Then the Brahma Sahampati thought: '**The Blessed One has consented to
> my request that he teach the Dhamma.**' And after paying homage to me,
> keeping me on the right, he thereupon departed at once.

Ariyapariyesana Sutta 26.21, Mahjjima Nikaya

Bodhisatvic principle is not there in Hindu scriptures. Why is the Boddhisatvic principle not there? The reason is that ordinary Jiva simply does not have the spiritual power to free all sentient beings from bondage. This type of work can only be done by an Avatara.

> Whenever there is decline of Dharma and ascendance of Adharma, then, O
> scion of the Bharata race! I manifest (incarnate) Myself in a body.

Gita 4.7

> For the protection of the good, for the destruction of the evil, and
> for the establishment  of Dharma, I am born from age to age.

Gita 4.8

Buddhism is a non-theistic system and there is going to be no Avatar to free people from bondage. Hinduism is a theistic system which says that Jiva even when free is too weak and powerless to help free all beings. An analogy would be that a Jiva is a dinghy while an Avatara is a steamship.

**So can the jiva do nothing?**

> I abide in all beings as their inner-most soul. Disregarding My
> presence within them, men make a show of worshiping Me through images.
> If one disregards Me present in all as their soul and Lord but
> ignorantly offers worship only to images, such worship is as
> ineffective as a sacrificial offering made in ashes. A man who
> persecutes Me residing in others, who is proud and haughty, who looks
> upon God as the other – such a person will never attain to peace of
> mind. If a man disregards and persecutes fellow beings, but worships
> Me in images with numerous rituals and rich offerings, I am not at all
> pleased with him for proffering such worship. A man should, however,
> worship Me in images, side by side with discharging his duties, which
> include the love of all beings, until he actually realises My presence
> in in himself and in all beings. As long as man is self-centred and
> makes an absolute distinction between himself and others (without
> recognising the unity of all in Me, the Inner Pervader), he will be
> subject to the great fear of Death (including every form of
> deprivation of self-interest). **So overcoming the separateness of a
> self-centred life, one should serve all beings with gifts, honour and
> love, recognising that such service is really being rendered to Me who
> reside in all beings as their innermost soul.**

Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.29.21-27

Yes an enlightened Jiva must serve others in the spirit of love and help a few people to attain enlightenment. However, it is not possible for him to do what the Buddhist bodhisattvic principle says. Such a thing is only possible for Avatar.

Comment: That is the most reasonable and logical answer i heard in a while! Thank You!